# How to track down jquery dependency issue with custom WordPress theme?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

I'm converting an HTML template I bought from Envato into a WP theme. I haven't worked with WordPress before, and not very experienced with jquery. Following any of the many guides online I've divided up the index.html file, have my front-page.php header.php and footer.php, and correctly enqueueing stylesheets and scripts in functions.php. I'm getting an error in the JS console that looks like jquery isn't loaded: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` in one of the JS files that came with the template.

I can load the original HTML file in a browser and it works fine. If I load the published page in WordPress none of the Javascript works. Viewing the two versions side by side in the developer console, I see that all of the stylesheets and scripts are the exact same files as those loaded by the HTML version, and they are in the same order and position (header/footer) as the HTML version. The only exception is that the main jquery version is being loaded by WordPress in the header section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.68.33/mcc-wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4" id="jquery-core-js"></script>
```

instead of the one included with the template, which loads before all the other scripts in the footer section:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've followed several of the previous posts here about similar problems, which seem to have been resolved by explicitly enqueueing jquery before the other scripts, which I did try with no difference in the outcome. This makes sense because many of the other scripts depend on jquery (fancybox, owl.carousel, ui.x, etc.) and are registered that way so WP is already loading it.

I've also tried loading the various scripts in the header vs. footer with no different results.

There are a couple of posts that point to the $ alias causing a conflict with WP, but it seems the solution is to edit a whole bunch (more than 20) of script files to use 'jquery' explicitly, which seems like it can't be the best way.

Has my inexperience caused me to overlook something?

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$` when dealing with wordpress. or do `const $=jQuery` first.